# How to manage radio selection in a dynamic nested structure

Tags: json, angular, dynamic, nested, radio-button

I have a list of objects that each object is in a nested structure:
For example:

```
{
"code" : 1,
"name" : "banks",
"isSelected" : false,
"children" : [ 
    [ 
        {
            "code" : 11,
            "name" : "bank1",
            "isSelected" : false,
            "children" : [ 
                [ 
                    {
                        "code" : 111,
                        "name" : "bank1.1.1",
                        "isSelected" : false

                    }, 
                    {
                        "code" : 112,
                        "name" : "bank1.1.2",
                        "isSelected" : false

                    }
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "code" : 12,
            "name" : "bank12",
             "isSelected" : false,
            "children" : [ 
                [ 
                    {
                        "code" :121,
                        "name" : "bank1.2.1",
                         "isSelected" : false,
                        "children" : [ 
                            [ 
                                {
                                    "code" : 1211,
                                    "name" : "bank1.2.1.1"
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "code" : 122,
                        "name" : "bank1.2.2"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

}

The nesting level is dynamic end may be different from object to object.
 In the client- side every object is a radio-button/checkbox that can be flagged.

In order to do it dynamically, I created a separate component whose job is to go over all the children and show them in the input.

in the main component:

```html
<div *ngFor="let listTags of tags" >
              <h5>{{ listTags.name }}</h5>
               <app-radio-list-tags [tagsList]="listTags"></app-radio-list-tags>
              </div>
```

The inner component  "app-radio-list-tags":

```html
<div *ngFor="let children of tagsList.children">
 <div class="col-md-12 row"> 
        <div *ngFor="let child of children;">
          <div class="col-md-12" >
            <label 
              <input   class="form-control"  type="radio" name="groupName{{ tagsList.code }}"  id="tagId{{ child.code }}" [value]="child.name" 
              (change)="changeSelectedTags($event) />
               <span child.name}}</span>  
               <button class="btn" [hidden]="!child.children" (click)="openMdlChilderTag(child) " > </button>  
              </label></div> </div></div>div>
```

If the child has a children than the component is called again (from modal that open from (click)="openMdlChilderTag(child))

I use the BehaviorSubject to hold the list and want to update the field isSelected in the object in  every choice

public tags = new BehaviorSubject([]);

What is the best way  to  change the list from  each internal object if it is selected? And mark those already selected on screen?
At the end I want to go over all the selected objects and keep them in a separate set.

How to update the list "tags" in the service in (change)="changeSelectedTags($event)?
Thank you so much